# Retrieve Every Fifth Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Goal:
Retrieve 1/5 of the whole data from the table test.
In other words, retrieve every fifth row in the table test.

Problem:
How to enable to retrieve data in every fifth row?
I know that you can use surrogate key such as ROW_NUMBER but it takes a lot of resources.

Information:
*table test contains 1 000 000 row.

Code:

Table Test
Column:
a - primary key with random numbers (int)
b - (nvarchar 254)
c - int

Comment: NO. it is not a homework!!!

Comment: Need to update my skills and I'm doin' it during my sparetime.

Comment: Looking at you rep, I myself won't suspect a homework. But that brings the question of what have you tried yourself?

Comment: Are you doing this inside some code (ex. java )? A basic logic can be using a loop. Increment the counter until it reaches 5, retrieve the row set the counter again to zero. repeat until the end.

Comment: I have tried it but I cannot retrieve the result. I don't have enough with experience in this context. SORRY!

Comment: One-fifth of the whole data or every fifth row? These 2 aren't necessarily the same.

Comment: No inside of a java or similiar. Just regular T-SQL is enough

Comment: If you need to retrieve 50 percent of data in the table and then how to retrieve it? you take a sample in ever odd or even row. THis thinking is based on statistics.

Comment: @FullMetalGame unless i'm missing something I would just use `select top 500000` or whatever half is

Comment: It only takes the first 500 000 row in the table. not every fifth row in the table (similiar as population from statistics)

Comment: @FullMetalGame if you're not doing an `order by` the db is free to return any rows whether you select every 5th row or `select top 1/5` so what's the difference?

Comment: This should be easy, just select the top 200000 rows (where 200000 is 1/5 the number of rows in the table).

Answer (score 2):

I have used ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL) for sequential increment value and ID%5 for every 5th sequence. Hope this helps.

**Test Data:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData')>0 DROP TABLE #TestData

CREATE TABLE #TestData (IDa INT, Descriptionb nvarchar (254), INTc int )

;WITH cte_TestData (IDa, Descriptionb , INTc,LEVEL)
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS IDa,CAST('ABC' AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Descriptionb ,5001 AS INTc, 1 as LEVEL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT td.IDa+1, td.Descriptionb , td.INTc+1, 1+td.LEVEL
    FROM cte_TestData td
    WHERE td.LEVEL <100

)
INSERT INTO #TestData
SELECT IDa, Descriptionb , INTc FROM cte_TestData ctd
WHERE IDa%3 = 0
```

**Query:**

```
;WITH CTE_PreFilter
AS
(
    SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS ID,
             IDa,
             Descriptionb,
             INTc
    FROM     #TestData
)
SELECT   IDa,
         Descriptionb,
         INTc
FROM     CTE_PreFilter
WHERE    ID%5 = 0
```

Comment: +1 . . . The question is asking for every fifth row, not a 20% random sample, so this looks like the better solution.

Comment: Appreciate the acknowledgment @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way to perform this (a random 20% sample of the rows) is:

```
   SELECT * FROM MyTable
   WHERE 0.2 >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), PrimaryKeyColumn) & 0x7fffffff AS float) / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)
```

> The TablePrimaryKeyColumn column is included in the CHECKSUM
>   expression so that NEWID() evaluates once per row to achieve sampling
>   on a per-row basis. The expression CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(),
>   SalesOrderID) & 0x7fffffff AS float / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)
>   evaluates to a random float value between 0 and 1.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108.aspx).

Comment: This is exciting, but it seems that the number should be 0.2. Am I wrong?

Comment: ooops! Thanks!..Updated.

Comment: And this one is a problem with the question: it doesn't state what does it mean by `every fifth row in the table`.

Comment: If you need to retrieve 50 percent of data in the table and then how to retrieve it? you take a sample in ever odd or even row. This thinking is based on statistics.

Comment: @FullMetalGame If you are basing on statistics, this answer looks enough. I mean IF there is no restriction on the data to be EXACTLY one in each five rows.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate a modulo 5 on the primary key.  It will still do a table scan, but avoid a potential sort that row_number might invoke.

Comment: Your approach would imply the primary key being ascending without gaps. How about values like 1,6,11,16 and so on?

Comment: @Lmu92 - the original post defined a column "a - primary key with random numbers (int)".  The randomness allows for modulo to provide a good-enough, easy-to-impliment, low resource-using answer.  If *your* data hs the seed, increment and increment you show you could still used this technique but with the formula `primary key mod 25 = 1` to get every fifth row.